# How to lazily reference ng-repeat dom elements in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, soundcloud

I'm working on a gallery of cover art for music releases. When a cover art is moused over, clickable titles for the songs on that release appear over the art. When a song title is clicked, the song is played/paused. Heres the simplified HTML:

```
<div class="image-container" ng-repeat="release in releases" ng-mouseover="imageMouseOver()" ng-mouseleave="imageMouseLeave()">
    <img ng-src="{{release.imageUrl}}" class="cover"/>
        <div ng-repeat="song in release.songs">
            <a class="imgText" ng-show="revealText" ng-click="clickTrack(song.url)" href="">
            {{song.title}}
            </a>
        </div>
    <canvas class="waveform" waveform-container id="{{release.id}}">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

Now I want to render a waveform of the song in the canvas element corresponding to that release, using the [waveform.js](http://www.waveformjs.org) library. This requires a reference to the canvas element in the javascript when the song is clicked:

```
$scope.clickTrack = function(url, release.id) {
    SC.get("http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=" + url, function(track) {
        // Do stuff to set up the waveform here, referencing the canvas element.
    });
}
```

My plan is to use a directive `waveform-container` that maps the id of the container to the container itself and attaching this to the scope:

```
app.directive("waveformContainer", [
    function() {
            return {
                link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    scope.waveformContainers[attrs.id] = element;
                }
            }
    }]);
```

I'm wondering if there are any better ways to do this, as this method is essentially calling document.getElementById().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just bind the url to the directive scope :

View

```
<div class="image-container" ng-repeat="release in releases" ng-mouseover="imageMouseOver()" ng-mouseleave="imageMouseLeave()">
    <img ng-src="{{release.imageUrl}}" class="cover"/>
        <div ng-repeat="song in release.songs">
            <a class="imgText" ng-show="revealText" ng-click="clickTrack(song.url)" href="">
            {{song.title}}
            </a>
        </div>
    <canvas class="waveform" waveform-container url="currentUrl" id="{{release.id}}">
    </canvas>
</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.clickTrack = function(url, release.id) {
    $scope.currentUrl = url;
}
```

Directive

```
app.directive("waveformContainer", [
    function() {
        return {
            scope: {
                url: "="
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch('url', function(val){
                    if(url) {
                        SC.get("http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=" + val, function(track) {
                            // Do stuff to set up the waveform here, referencing the canvas element.
                            // it is "element"
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
         }
    }]);
```